# BingException error while running opensearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Could some one provide insight

I am configuring OpenSearch two nodes (Node1 and Node2 )

Node 2 is up and running no errors
for Node 1 I am getting Bind exception error. except node.name and ip address both configuration is same

Good Node :

```
cluster.name: test
node.name: testdata-1
node.master: true  
path.data: /opt/opensearch-1.3.6/data  
path.logs: /opt/opensearch-1.3.6/logs  
network.host: 10.88.44.18  
http.port: 9200  
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.88.44.18", "10.88.44.170"]  
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.88.44.18"]  
plugins.security.disabled: true  
network.tcp.reuse_address: true
```

Bad Node :

```
cluster.name: test
node.name: testdata-2  
node.master: true  
path.data: /opt/opensearch-1.3.6/data  
path.logs: /opt/opensearch-1.3.6/logs  
network.host: 10.88.44.170  
http.port: 9200  
discovery.seed_hosts: ["10.88.44.170", "10.88.44.18"]  
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["10.88.44.170"]  
plugins.security.disabled: true
```

network.tcp.reuse_address: true

No service running in port 9200 in bad node   (netstat -l -n)

Comment: cluster.initial_master_nodes must be the same on both nodes otherwise the cluster cannot be bootstrapped

Comment: Error   BindTransportException[Failed to bind to 10.88.44.170:[9300-9400]]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
Likely root cause: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: it means something might already be listening on 10.88.44.170:9300, make sure you don't have another running process on that port... but your config also needs to be fixed as per my first comment

Comment: I  pass same IP to "cluster.initial_master_nodes"  still same error

Comment: No service running with 9200 to 9300 in bad node

Comment: How does your `/etc/hosts` file look like on both hosts?